# JQuery Signature not working for IE <= 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using JQuery Singature and I encountered this Error Message for above IE version:

```
Message: Canvas element does not support 2d context. jSignature cannot proceed.
```

update : After Added the (;) in the flashcanvas.js

The Problem is the Same:

Message: Expected ';' 
    flashcanvas.swf

```
Code: 0
```

I have downloaded the `flashcanvas.swf` and `flashcanvas.js` from:

https://github.com/brinley/jSignature/blob/master/libs/flashcanvas.js
https://github.com/brinley/jSignature/blob/master/libs/flashcanvas.swf

these two files I placed them in a Folder called Script.

It does not matter if I include or did not include flashcanvas.swf  What I need to do?

here the javascript

```
 <!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/flashcanvas.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/flashcanvas.swf"></script> 
<![endif]-->  

<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jSignature.js"></script>   

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function (){
    $("#divSignature").jSignature({width:400, height:140, mousedown:function(){}});
    });

</script>
```

Comment: did you try adding the html5 tags to the DOM?

Comment: For IE ver 10 and higher it is OK. Now, How to add html5 tag to Above IE version <= 9 since they dont support Html5.

Answer (score 1):

Just a syntax error, simply update the following at line 928 of flashcanvas.js:

```
function getSwfUrl(window) {
    return ( (window[FLASH_CANVAS + "Options"] || {})["swfPath"] || BASE_URL ) + "flashcanvas.swf"; //Added semicolon
}
```

IE tend to be less lenient towards Javascript errors, which can be a good thing for programmers learning the language. Browsers like Chrome can accommodate a fair amount of JS errors and still correctly execute a script.

Comment: are you sure that is an error? i mean you don't need to use `;` every time, and less when is about the last statement http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: Your article does say it clearly `JavaScript implementations differ`. It's likely to be 'expected' for IE as the error message suggest.

Comment: I did as per your instruction. Now, inside the Div there is a red X something like image is not displayed. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Hi @MilkBottle, can you share the link to your page?

Comment: @James This aspnet Website in LAN. No external access now. What seems to be the problems? I have added the flashcanvas.js and flashcanvas.swf I want to support IE 8/9.